# Avoiding endless virtual look-up

Tags: c++, function, templates, virtual

Consider this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Base {
protected:
    virtual std::string addMoreDetail (std::string&) const = 0;
};

template <int...> class Derived;

template <>
class Derived<0, 0> : private Base {
private:
    bool b;
protected:
    virtual std::string description() const {return "Whatever1";}
    std::string finalize (std::string& str) const {return b ? addMoreDetail(str) : str;}
};

template <>
class Derived<1, 0> : private Base {
protected:
    virtual std::string description() const {return "Whatever2";}
    std::string finalize (std::string& str) const {return addMoreDetail(str);}
};

template <int N>
class Derived<N, 0, 0> : public Derived<N, 0> {
public:
    virtual std::string description() const override {
        std::string str = Derived<N, 0>::description();   return this->finalize(str);
        // Can this be moved up somehow?
    }
private:
    inline std::string addMoreDetail (std::string& s) const {return s + " Detail1";}
};

template <int N>
class Derived<N, 0, 1> : public Derived<N, 0> {
public:
    virtual std::string description() const override {
        std::string str = Derived<N, 0>::description();   return this->finalize(str);
        // Can this be moved up somehow?
    }
private:
    inline std::string addMoreDetail (std::string& s) const {return s + " Detail2";}
};

int main() {
    std::cout << Derived<0, 0, 0>().description() << '\n';  // Whatever1
    std::cout << Derived<0, 0, 1>().description() << '\n';  // Whatever1
    std::cout << Derived<1, 0, 0>().description() << '\n';  // Whatever2 Detail1
    std::cout << Derived<1, 0, 1>().description() << '\n';  // Whatever2 Detail2
}
```

My goal is simple.  I want to avoid writing

```
std::string str = Derived<N, 0>::description();   return this->finalize(str);
```

twice by moving it up in the hierarchy.

This is my temporary solution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template <int...> class Derived;

class Base {
protected:
    virtual std::string description() const = 0;
    virtual std::string addMoreDetail (std::string&) const = 0;
    template <int N> std::string descriptionBase (const Derived<N, 0>* derived) const {
//  std::string str = derived->description();   return derived->finalize(str);  // Endless look-up!
        std::string str = derived->staticDescription();   return derived->finalize(str);
    }
};

template <>
class Derived<0, 0> : protected Base {
private:
    bool b;
    friend Base;
protected:
    virtual std::string description() const {return staticDescription();}
    static std::string staticDescription() {return "Whatever1";}
    std::string finalize (std::string& str) const {return b ? addMoreDetail(str) : str;}
};

template <>
class Derived<1, 0> : protected Base {
    friend Base;
protected:
    virtual std::string description() const {return staticDescription();}
    static std::string staticDescription() {return "Whatever2";}
    std::string finalize (std::string& str) const {return addMoreDetail(str);}
};

template <int N>
class Derived<N, 0, 0> : public Derived<N, 0> {
public:
    std::string description() const override {return this->template descriptionBase<N>(this);}
private:
    inline std::string addMoreDetail (std::string& s) const {return s + " Detail1";}
};

template <int N>
class Derived<N, 0, 1> : public Derived<N, 0> {
public:
    std::string description() const override {return this->template descriptionBase<N>(this);}
private:
    inline std::string addMoreDetail (std::string& s) const {return s + " Detail2";}
};

int main() {
    std::cout << Derived<0, 0, 0>().description() << '\n';  // Whatever1
    std::cout << Derived<0, 0, 1>().description() << '\n';  // Whatever1
    std::cout << Derived<1, 0, 0>().description() << '\n';  // Whatever2 Detail1
    std::cout << Derived<1, 0, 1>().description() << '\n';  // Whatever2 Detail2
}
```

But this doesn't actually work in my program because `description()` is not static as it depends on data members.  Yet if I use

```
std::string str = derived->description();   return derived->finalize(str);
```

instead of

```
std::string str = derived->staticDescription();   return derived->finalize(str);
```

I get a run-time endless virtual look-up because it keeps going back to the original.  How to avoid this?  Or is there a better way to accomplish my goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your `staticDescription` methods non-virtual non-static member functions, i.e. leave your code as it is and remove `static` when definining the `staticDescription` methods. Maybe you want to rename `staticDescription` into `doGetDescription` or so.

The usual solution, probably, would be using the template-method pattern (or non-virtual interface pattern):

```
class BaseClass {
public:
   std::string getDescription () const {
      return this->doGetDescription ();
   }

private:
   virtual std::string doGetDescription () const = 0;
};

class FirstDerived : public BaseClass {
   std::string doGetDescription () const override { return "First"; }
};

class SecondDerived : public BaseClass {
   std::string doGetDescription () const override { return "Second"; }
};

BaseClass & b = SecondDerived {};
std::cout << b.getDescription () << std::endl;
```